# Select specific column in elasticseacrh

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a sample json in elastic search.

```
"snum": 1,
"dept" : 1
"cards": [
 {
  "card_num": 1,
  "dimensions": {
    "width": 1,
    "depth": 4,
    "height": 1
  },
  other_card_details{
  }
 ]
```

How to write a query in elastic search to fetch only the dimensions from cards array?

My mapping looks like this:

```
"properties": {
"snum": {"type": "integer"},
"dept": {"type": "integer"},
"cards": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "card_num": {"type": "integer"},
        "dimensions": {
            "properties": {
                "width": {"type": "float"},
                "depth": {"type": "float"},
                "height": {"type": "float"}
            }
        },
    },
}
```

}

Comment: What does your mapping look like?

Comment: added the mapping

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly and your goal is to return only the `cards.dimensions` field in your query responses, you need to specify that field in the `_source` parameter of your search

```
{
  "query": { ... },
  "_source": ["cards.dimensions"]
}
```

Relevant documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/search-fields.html#source-filtering

**Update based on comment:** 
If your goal is to get a JSON that looks like

```
[{
  "dimensions": { ... }
},{
  "dimensions": { ... }
}]
```

you will need to post-process the response JSON and extract the fields you want. The best you can get using Elasticsearch only is by filtering the response fields showing only the hits:

```
GET elasticsearch-hostname:9200/index-name/_query?filter_path=hits.hits._source
{
  "_source": ["cards.dimensions"]
}
```

And you will get:

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "cards" : [
            {
              "dimensions" : {
                "depth" : 4,
                "width" : 1,
                "height" : 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then, you can post-process your response to make `cards.dimensions` the root field. E.g., by using `jq`:

```
curl -XGET "elasticsearch-hostname:9200/index-name/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d'{
          "_source": ["cards.dimensions"]
        }' \
    | jq '.hits.hits[]._source.cards'
```

Comment: I tried with this. but its returing the complete data , I need only dimensions dict

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "complete data"? also the other fields (like `snum`, `dept`)?

Comment: I am getting the whole json object with the query you mentioned. I want to fetch only  dimensions data -- "dimensions": {
    "width": 1,
    "depth": 4,
    "height": 1
  },

Comment: If you mean that your json response should contain only the "cards.dimensions" field (and sub-fields), you can't achieve that with Elasticsearch only, but you will need to post-process the query response. The best you can get is to drop all fields but `hits.hits._source`, which is the root field for your `cards.dimensions` object

Comment: Hi @CodeCool, was your question answered?